# Three instances of EL6, two show updates for openssl, the third does not

Tags: centos6, yum, update

In remediation of [DROWN](https://access.redhat.com/security/vulnerabilities/drown), I need to update openssl packages on several EL6 servers.  SSLv2 was turned off a long time ago but need to get these binaries up to date.

I found that yum update presented the updated openssl binary on two of the machines, but not the third.  The repositories on all three machines are identical.

Is there a reason yum would present an update to one box but not the other (assuming again that repo configuration is the same across both machines)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> assuming again that all repo data is the same across both machines

That's not an assumption I would make.

Yum caches data for improved performance.  If one system pulled the headers from the repo recently it may have different data cached than the others, even if they're pointing at the same repos.

Run `yum clean metadata` and newer updates should show up.

See: [Working with Yum Cache](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Working_with_Yum_Cache.html) in the RHEL 6 deployment guide.

Comment: Thanks.  I read the docs and see how to do this now.  Not sure the question was worthy of a downvote, but I've upvoted your answer and will select it momentarily.